# Can't access CakePHP API endpoint via ReactJS. Only through the browser

Tags: reactjs, api, cakephp, axios, cakephp-routing

I am trying to build a REST API for my server via CakePHP.  I thought I had it working as I can receive the JSON responses via the web browser however when trying to access the same route via ReactJS, the Controllers Action is not actually firing.

Reading the CakePHP docs I really should only have to implement these lines of code to get the API working (According to the docs) and I did:

`/config/routes.php`

`Router::scope('/', function($routes) {
     $routes->setExtensions(['json']);
     $routes->resources('Users');
 });`

Here is the API Endpoint I want to hit:

```
`public function signUp() {
     $file = fopen("error_log.txt", "w");
     $txt = "firing endpoint";
     $fwrite($file, $txt);
     $fclose($file);
     $response = $this->response;
     $responseText = [
         "status" => "200",
         "message" => "User added successfully"
     ];
     $response = $response->withType("application/json")
         ->withStringBody(json_encode($responseText));
     return $response;
}`
```

Here I am successfully hitting that endpoint via the browser.  My log message also appears in the `error_log.txt` file

[image]

Here is where I'm making a request via ReactJS:

`handleRequest = () => {
         console.log('making request');
         axios({
             method: 'get',
             url: 'https://157.230.176.243/users/register.json',
             data: {
                 email: this.state.email,
                 password: this.state.password
             }
         })

             .then(function(response) {
                 console.log('got response');
                 console.log(response);
             })

             .catch(function(error) {
                 console.log('got error');
                 console.log(error);
             })

             .then(function(data) {
                 console.log('always executed');
                 console.log(data);
             });
}`

When I make this request via ReactJS I get a `XHR failed loading: OPTIONS "https://157.230.176.243/users/register.json"`

Also when making this request via ReactJS my log message does not get written to `error_log.txt`

Comment: Have you checked all the "_Why this might have happened_" points that Postman is showing there? Especially the (self signed) SSL certificate one, given that Chrome shows that your certificate is invalid?

Comment: @ndm Yes I followed postmans hint and turned off SSL Certificate Verification however that did not help

Comment: Does your `error_log.txt` get written to when you try to hit it with Postman? (Also, why not using Cake's built-in logging, via `$this->log(...)` in your controller?)

Comment: @GregSchmidt I have updated the question if you wouldn't mind reading back through it.  I had a proxy issue with postman and have successfully received a response in Postman.  However I'm still not receiving responses through ReactJS requests

Answer (score 1):

Ok I finally figured out what was wrong. I have my React Development server running on

`157.230.176.243:3001`

and my CakePHP API served on that same server,

`157.230.176.243`

React didn't like it that I was passing the full URL of the API to the `fetch()`

call. I switched my React code to

`url: "/users/register.json"` 
and it works fine.